# How to visualize wind data with geom_quiver using fewer, bigger arrows

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial

The code below overlays wind speed and direction over the Great Lakes.
1) There are too many arrows. How do I average most of them so I can place just 3-5 large arrows on the map?

2) Why are some of the arrows so small, if their speed affects their colour?
I don't understand this from help(geom_quiver)

> vecsize
>   By default (NULL), vectors sizing is automatically determined. If a grid can be identified, they will be scaled to the grid, if not, the vectors will not be scaled. By specifying a numeric input here, the length of all arrows can be adjusted. Setting vecsize to zero will prevent scaling the arrows.

I believe these vectors are scaled to the grid. But isn't the grid evenly distributed?

---

```
library("ggmap")
library("ggquiver")
library("tidyverse")
library("dplyr")
library("scales")
library(rWind)

# Wind Data
# Global Forecast System (GFS) of the USA's National Weather Service (NWS)
# wind.dl(yyyy, mm, dd, tt, lon1, lon2, lat1, lat2, type = "read-data")
# Time: tt  Options: 00:00 - 03:00 - 06:00 - 09:00 - 12:00 - 15:00 - 18:00 - 21:00 (UTC)
wind_data <- wind.dl(2018, 3, 16, 18,-94, -70, 41, 49)

wind_data_fit <- wind_data %>% 
  wind.fit()

wind_data <- rename(wind_data, "u" = "ugrd10m (m s-1)", "v" = "vgrd10m (m s-1)")
df <- mutate(wind_data_fit, u = wind_data$u, v = wind_data$v)

median_speed = median(df$speed)


qmplot(lon, lat, data = df, 
       extent = "panel", 
       geom = "blank", 
       zoom = 6, 
       maptype = "watercolor") + 

  scale_colour_gradient2(low = "white", mid = "black",
                         high = "firebrick", midpoint = median_speed, space = "Lab",
                         na.value = "grey50", guide = "colourbar") +

  geom_quiver(aes(u = u, v = v, colour = speed),
              center = TRUE,
              alpha = 0.7,
              size = 0.7, # Line width
              vecsize = 2) # Length of straight segment
```

Answer (score 3):

`geom_quiver` is plotting an arrow for every row of data. One option to reduce the number arrows is to plot an arrow for, say, every *n*th row of data. In the example below, we plot every other row (so *n=2*), halving the number of arrows. The only change necessary is in the `data` argument in the first line of plot code:

```
qmplot(lon, lat, data = df[seq(1,nrow(df),2), ],
```

[image]

Compare this with the original plot:

[image]

You can reduce the arrows further by selecting whichever rows of data you'd like to plot on the map. See below for an example. In this case, note that I've used the full data frame `df` as the data argument to `qmplot` and the filtered data frame as the data argument to `geom_quiver`. This is to ensure that the map includes the entire lat-lon extent of the full data frame, even though we are plotting arrows for only a few of the points:

```
# Latitudes to keep
lat.keep = unique(df$lat)[seq(2, length(unique(df$lat)), 5)]

qmplot(lon, lat, data = df,
       extent = "panel", geom="blank", zoom = 6, maptype = "watercolor") + 
  scale_colour_gradient2(low = "yellow", mid = "black",
                         high = "firebrick", midpoint = median_speed, space = "Lab",
                         na.value = "grey50", guide = "colourbar") +
  geom_quiver(data=df %>%
                 filter(lat %in% lat.keep) %>% 
                 group_by(lat) %>%
                 slice(seq(2, n(), 11)), # Keep 1/11th of longitudes
              aes(u = u, v = v, colour = speed),
              center = TRUE, alpha = 1, size = 1, vecsize = 0.9)
```

[image]

Comment: Still, too many arrows. Do you know how to average both latitude and longitude?